# ERROR in document is not defined in angular 9

Tags: angular-cli-v9

```
   document.querySelector('.pcoded-inner-navbar').classList.add('scroll-sidebar');
```

I comment all code related to documment but till when I try to build using ng build I found ERROR in document is not defined. plz help

Comment: Amol Did you figure this one out?